# python bokeh unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, bokeh

I was wondering if there were any strategies or implementations to unit testing of a bokeh plot rendered within a Django template other than looking at the response status code of the Django view?

Here is my code snippet below,

```
#views.py

def bokeh_view(request):
    ...
    script,div = components(mygraph)
    return render(request, 'graph.html',{'script': script, 'div': div})

#graph.html
...
{{ div | safe }}
{{ script | safe }}
...

#test.py

def test_dashboard(self):
    responce = self.client.post('/bokeh_view/', follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I also have user forms which may affect the database tables from which will then be graphed. I do not have access to selenium currently so all tests are running via Django's test runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is probably to encapsulate plot creation in some function, and then test that you are passing that function the parameters that you should be. Otherwise you are testing Bokeh itself, which is redundant.